# How to analize crash dumps android

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

I have just put my first app on Google Play (a simple game with Libgdx) and recieved a first crash report. But I don't know how to analyze it. I have searched google and found a few guides but they are quite advanced and they don't really tell how to know what went wrong. I imagined that crash reports would include an exception type and a line number in which error happend, like in adb. But obviously, they don't. Here is my crash report:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100/GT-I9100:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9100XWMS2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 6133, tid: 6133, name: com.mbostic  >>> com.mbostic <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 4003b7e8  r1 00000080  r2 fffffd76  r3 00000000
    r4 4003b7e8  r5 4003b7d8  r6 fffffd76  r7 000000f0
    r8 00000004  r9 4cab82b0  sl 00000000  fp 416db9f0
    ip 00000000  sp be9345a0  lr 4013bfa8  pc 4014e9d0  cpsr 600b0010
    d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
    d4  0000000000000000  d5  3f80000000000000
    d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 0000000000002968  d17 0000000014d20903
    d18 0000000014d1df9b  d19 0000000000000000
    d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
    d22 0000000000000000  d23 bff0000000000000
    d24 3f71111120000000  d25 8000000000000000
    d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 bf9b4e81c0000000
    d28 8000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 20000013

backtrace:
    #00  pc 000219d0  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
    #01  pc 0000efa4  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
    #02  pc 0000f004  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
    #03  pc 000542eb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #04  pc 00068e29  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #05  pc 00027f20  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #06  pc 0002f418  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
    #07  pc 0002cabc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #08  pc 00061e05  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
    #09  pc 00069fc3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #10  pc 00027f20  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #11  pc 0002f418  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
    #12  pc 0002cabc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #13  pc 00061b23  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
    #14  pc 0004b287  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #15  pc 00051b83  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #16  pc 000528a7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
    #17  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
    #18  pc 0000e42b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
    #19  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
    4014e9b0 e5900000 e2601000 e0100001 116f0f10  
    4014e9c0 12600020 e12fff1e e1a0c007 e3a070f0  
    4014e9d0 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e eafffff9  
    4014e9e0 e1a0c007 e1a03002 e1a02001 e3a01000  
    4014e9f0 e3a070f0 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e  
    4014ea00 e1a0c007 e1a02001 e3a01001 e3a070f0  
    4014ea10 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e e1a0000d  
    4014ea20 e12fff1e e92d50f0 e3a07025 ef000000  
    4014ea30 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
    4014ea40 ea006ff9 f5d0f000 f5d1f000 e1500001  
    4014ea50 13520000 03a00000 012fff1e e1a03000  
    4014ea60 e352000c 5a000008 f5d0f020 f5d1f020  
    4014ea70 e0d300b2 e0d1c0b2 e050000c 112fff1e  
    4014ea80 e2522001 1afffff9 e12fff1e e92d4010  
    4014ea90 e3130002 0a000005 e0d300b2 e0d1c0b2  
    4014eaa0 e2422001 e050000c 18bd4010 112fff1e  

code around lr:
    4013bf88 e5946000 ebfffe8a e5941000 e1a03007  
    4013bf98 e1a02006 e1a00004 e2011001 ebfffd5f  
    4013bfa8 e1a04000 e1a00005 ebfffe40 e374006e  
    4013bfb8 03a0006e 13a00000 e8bd80f8 e3520000  
    4013bfc8 e92d4030 e1a05000 e24dd00c e1a04001  
    4013bfd8 0a000007 e1a01002 e1a0000d e1a02003  
    4013bfe8 ebfffd12 e3500000 b3a0006e ba000003  
    4013bff8 e1a0200d e1a00005 e1a01004 ebffffda  
    4013c008 e28dd00c e8bd8030 e3a03000 eaffffea  
    4013c018 e3a02000 eafffffb e3a03001 eaffffe6  
    4013c028 eaffffd1 e304cdd3 e92d4010 e341c062  
    4013c038 e1a0e002 e084329c e3043240 e340300f  
    4013c048 e24dd008 e1a0200d e1a0c324 e3a04ffa  
    4013c058 e06eec94 e58dc000 e0030e93 e58d3004  
    4013c068 ebffffc1 e28dd008 e8bd8010 e5903000  
    4013c078 e92d4070 e1a04000 e1a05001 e3130002
```